# xpenoboot dsm 5.2-5644 - updated to dsm 7.0 would like to recover data

Tags: dsm

I managed to click on update system as dsm recommended (i only seen the server online and didn't know its not factory synology nas, and never worked with synology NAS before, my bad, anyway)

it is a xpenoboot dsm 5.2-5644, with a wild config one hdd in raid with an ssd (neither the same manufacturer, nor the same size, lets move on).

I went to the server location to fix the issue, and of course i cant do anything at there, now its sitting here and waiting to at least try to recover data.

I found a threat in here so I tried to install a clean setup on a new hdd, with the two other drives out of the built. As earlier I saved a system config file, i managed to install the new dsm 5.2, (with the "original/old" usb boot drive) and recovered the system configuration on the new install, now every user usergroup etc. is as it was on the previous install. i tried to reconnect the two old drives, but then it boots like before the new install, and of course wont load the dsm. i connected the new hdd in the sata1 the two old ones to sata 2 and 3.

i searched for other threads with others similar issues, and found maybe i should edit the usb syslinux.cfg but the previous and new install is using the same dsm version the same serial number, i dont know anything about linux, so i dont know what sould i do next. maybe the "vid" or "pid" values can help me.

so first i would like to run my newly installed dsm 5.2 (on the new hdd) with the two old drives in the server too, then i would like to reconnect the data pertitions with hopefully no data corruption.

its also good for me if i can recover the data on the raid, then i can make a new install and put the data back on.

as i wrote my linux knowledge is equall with 0 or less, so if it needs putty or something please advise from line to line.

please help

1; working dsm 5.2 (security issues)

2; saved system config file

3; clicked in dsm controll panel the update buttton (from 5.2 to 7.x  i know, i'm insane)

4; tried to find NAS with assistant, not found

5; physically connected to the NAS, not found, on the NAS screen  "protected file missing ...." a lot and a few errors

6; removed the two drives (one ssd, one hdd they managed somehow to connected in RAID)

7; add new HDD

8; installed dsm5.2-5644 with the "old/original" boot usb on the new hdd

9; everything runs smooth

10; restored the earlier saved system config file

---

thats where i am know,

i tried to reconnect the two drives but then it trys to boot the corrupted system not the new one

Thanks for your thoughts on this. And have fun if you like this kind of stuff

Answer (score 0):

It was actually pretty easy:
maybe it will help others

1; forget the new hdd, put the original 2 back in,
2; start xpenoboot in install mode,
3; use synology assistant, it will say its migratable, click double
4; make a clean install, (the data part will remain, only the config and third party addons will be lost
5; chose the origynal dsm5.2-5644.5.pat and install
6; start up your system in synology assistant,
7; in control panel restore your saved system config
8; everything is working properly,